# Letter "E" Stopped Working - Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

Can't login to my Linux Min 19 Cinnamon Laptop because I singular key stopped working! Any ideas around this?

Comment: Plug in a keyboard.

Comment: @Wildcard I'm literally on vacation in the middle of nowhere and didn't bring one ughh lol

Comment: Login and change the keyboard layout. (But how to login). Or is there an onscreen keyboard option on the login screen, that can be activated via the mouse.

Comment: Use your fingerprint sensor if you have one (and configured).

Comment: Use `ssh` from your smartphone to login and change configuration as necessary. (You do have `ssh` on your smartphone, don't you?)

Comment: If you can break in at the grub prompt (or other bootloader, but most people use grub) then append `init=/bin/bash` to the boot command. When the system boots, run `mount -o remount,rw /` to make the disk partition writeable, and then run `passwd darria` or whatever the user name is to change the password.

Comment: @icarus `remount` has an `e` in it.

Comment: @AnonymousDarria How did you type in the `e`s in your question? Do you have access to another machine?

Comment: @Sparhawk indeed it does. At this stage however he can do things like `X=$\`\x65\`` to make `${X}` a lower case e. so then he can type `mount -o r${X}mount,rw /`

Comment: @icarus Nice one. You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the simplest solution is to just connect an external keyboard, which might be via USB, bluetooth, or an onscreen one operated by a mouse.

The OP says that he doesn't have another keyboard available.

If it is possible to break in at the grub prompt (or whatever bootloader is being used) then you can append `init=/bin/bash` to the command line, and continue the boot. The system will continue and will end up with a shell prompt in a sort of half booted stage.

At this stage we want to create a new password without the letter `e` so it can be entered with the faulty keyboard. However, the disk is in a read-only state, so can't store an updated password. Type

```
X=$'\x65'
mount -o r${X}mount,rw /
```

to remount the / partition without needing the letter `e`. $'\xNN' is bash syntax which allows you input a character by hex digits, `$'\x45'` is `E` and `$'\x65'` is `e`.  Then change the password for the user

```
passwd darria
```

to chnage the password of the user `darria`. Save all the changes to disk by running

```
sync
```

and waiting a few seconds, then reboot the machine (the power button for 10 seconds may be your best option), and log in with the new password.